# Is there a way to have a user enter a url query and have a single function filter a database?

Tags: python, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm playing with the Django rest framework and PostgreSQL, building an API that returns data on all of the stats from this NBA season. Rather than having a function to return stats for each category, such as:

```
 @api_view(['GET'])
def sortByRebounds(request):
    """Returns all stats in the database sorted by rebounds per game"""
    string = Nba_stats.objects.values_list('name', 'team', 'rpg').order_by('rpg').reverse()
    return Response(string)
```

It possible to have a single function capable of filtering and returning data based on what the user types in the url?

For example a function called `sortBy` that takes in a category as a parameter and a url `"api/sortby/<str:category>/"` where a user can type `"api/sortby/rebounds"` and receive the data on rebounds or `"api/sortby/assists"` and receive everything on assists.